# To list reports according to their types in Salesforce

Tags: reports-api

I want to pull the reports in Salesforce according to their types.
For example, I want to get a list of all reports created in Salesforce in Account type, how can I do this.

Comment: Hello , does this discussion answer your question [Is it possible to query/find reports using a particular report type?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341779/is-it-possible-to-query-find-reports-using-a-particular-report-type) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Apex it is still not achievable , as mentioned in this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdaNgUAJ/query-for-report-type-in-soql-query-on-reports) , hence Report Type is only accessible through the Metadata API for reports .

Also I am referring posts and discussions which might help you with your current scenario .
[Is there is any way to get standard field api name from standard report types reports in apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173367/is-there-is-any-way-to-get-standard-field-api-name-from-standard-report-types-re?rq=1) ,

[How to get reportType for many reports](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79737/how-to-get-reporttype-for-many-reports?rq=1)

and

[Is there any way where we can check the reports count on Specific report type.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000PkHwGSAV?_ga=2.137801840.1978414820.1684744078-1455979405.1678225982)

Hope it helps !